# Why does my RSA key look different on my server than when I try to connect?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, scp

I am trying to connect to my Linux server using PuTTY (and SCP specifically) from Windows. When I first tried to connect, as when I try to connect from any new machine, I get a warning about connecting to an “unknown server” and adding its key to my cache.

From Windows it says “The server’s rsa2 key fingerprint is:”
and then provides something that looks like this:

```
0a:34:a3:43:af (etc)
```

To verify it, I `ssh`’d into my server changed to `/etc/ssh/` and ran:

```
for file in *sa_key.pub; do ssh-keygen -lf $file; done
```

To print out all of the fingerprints of my files.

The output looked quite different, more like this:

```
2048 SHA256:ZAGZABCSD4+abcfe5ffff344444fff32323 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

In other words not a colon separated list of numbers at all. Could somebody tell me the difference and how I could find the correct colon separated list of values for the fingerprint?

Comment: They key fingerprint is not the key itself, but a hash of the key and is displayed in hex pairs as above.  If you're feeling paranoid, its a good idea to print out the server's key fingerprint or post it on a web site you control for reference using `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parts of openssh are using MD5 hashes, and some are using SHA256 hashes.  In your case, it seems like your client is providing an md5 hash, whereas your server ssh-keygen us using SHA256.

You can calculate the hash yourself.  If you get the host key from the .pub file, it looks like this, ellipsis to replace many characters:

```
   AAAAB3[...]==
```

Then you can do the hashes yourself:

md5:

```
echo "AAAAB3[...]==" | base64 -d | md5sum
679e19234b295ee432a3920c30fda6ac
```

sha:

```
echo "AAAAB3[...]==" | base64 -d | sha1sum
41a53770303a0776a1378239e2ee0fd825705c74
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is old as of July/2019 , incase anyone falls here with the same question, with Putty on windows the servers host key fingerprint is drawn out in md5 format (colon seprated as described by the OP)

So on your linux OpenSSH host with terminal access you can check the ssh_host keys fingerprints with:

in md5 format
    `ssh-keyscan localhost | ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f -`

or in SHA256 format
    `ssh-keyscan localhost | ssh-keygen -l -E SHA256 -f -`

or with visual ASCII art representation of the key
    `ssh-keyscan localhost | ssh-keygen -l -v -f -`